# C program read integers and display it reversed order side by side to inout array

Tags: c

C program that asks user to input numbers and then reverse the numbers. How I can print the arrays side by side? It prints the arrays below each others now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main(){
    int a[N], i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    for(i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only keep the first loop, and in it you need to do e.g. `printf("%d %d\n", a[i], a[reverse_index]);` where you need to figure out the `reverse_index` (using `i` and `N` and some arithmetic).

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you can get array elements in reverse by indexing them from the back:

```c
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", a[i], a[N - i - 1]);
    }
```